# Android doesnt load the listview if i add 4 data to the list

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview, android-listview

Currently i am working on listview data passing to another activity when ever i run this it works fine the first time it take the 3 listview data thats are bagnumber cod and ordernumber  and uploads in the another activity when i add the subnumber and run it and press the get button to get the listview its doesn't load the list

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        TextView ver;
        TextView name;
        TextView api;
        TextView sn;
        Button Btngetdata;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        private static String url = "http://216.185.116.35/LOGISTIC/WebServices/json/getDeliveriItems_bak.ashx?id=485";

        private static final String TAG_OS = "android";

        private static final String TAG_VER = "BagNumber";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "COD";
        private static final String TAG_API = "OrderNo";
        private static final String TAG_SON = "Subordernumber";


        JSONArray android = null;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



            Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
            Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     new JSONParse().execute();


                }
            });


        }



        private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
             private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                 ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
                 name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
                 api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
                 sn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subordernumber);

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();



            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                super.onPostExecute(json); 
                pDialog.dismiss();
                try {


                      android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                       for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                       JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                       String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                       String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                       String api = c.getString(TAG_API);
                       String Subordernumber = c.getString(TAG_SON);
                       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                       map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                       map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                       map.put(TAG_API, api);
                       map.put(TAG_SON, Subordernumber);
                       oslist.add(map);
                       }
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                       SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,R.layout.list_v,new String[] { TAG_VER }, new int[] {
                                       R.id.vers});
                       list.setAdapter(adapter);
                       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                       @Override
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                       String ver = oslist.get(position).get(COD);
                       String name = oslist.get(position).get(TAG_NAME);
                       String api = oslist.get(position).get(TAG_API);
                       String Subordernumber = oslist.get(position).get(TAG_SON);


                       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
                       intent.putExtra("TAG_NAME", name);
                       intent.putExtra("TAG_API", api);
                       intent.putExtra("TAG_SON", Subordernumber);
                       startActivity(intent);

                       }
                       });
             }
        }

        }
```

YourActivity Class

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "COD";
    private static final String TAG_API = "OrderNo";
    private static final String TAG_SON = "Subordernumber";


    @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.itemlistrow); 

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String COD = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_NAME); 
            String OrderNo = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_API);
            String Subordernumber = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_SON);

            TextView lblcodno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cod);
            TextView lblordernumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ordernumber);
            TextView lblsubordernumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subordernumber);

            lblsubordernumber.setText(Subordernumber);
            lblcodno.setText(COD);
            lblordernumber.setText(OrderNo);


}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe

`String Subordernumber = oslist.get(position).get("TAG_SON");`

should be

`String Subordernumber = oslist.get(position).get(TAG_SON);`

(without the quotes around `TAG_SON`).

Comment: @Jeshurun is correct its not working for you beacuse your values for `TAG_SON` are different in both `Activity`. They need to be same.

Comment: ok I changed the TAG_SON value in YourActivity Class  activity but its not loading the listview

Comment: What `ListView`?? I don't see any `ListView` in `YourActivity`

Comment: sorry i meant its still not loading the list when i press the getdata button